# Media volume getting set to Max , i want it at 70%

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an app that lets users set an alarm. I am using media player to play the alert sound. I would like to set the media volume to 70 % . THis is how I am doing it.

```
      @Override
   protected void onResume(){

 super.onResume();

 mDbHelper.open();

 AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
 originalVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); // we get the current volume from the system
 mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 70, 0);




 mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.midi_sound);
 mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true); 
 mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);// we set the sound to loop.
 if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){// if the media player is not playing , make it start
        mediaPlayer.start();
}


}
```

But the volume gets set to max. My users may have their earphones on while using the app and i do not want to defend them with max volume. How do i set the volume to 70% instead of max volume?

Note: I will be setting the volume back to original volume in the onPause method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5215504/2003486), the values of volume vary from 0.0f to 1.0f, so you can put the value accordingly, as explained in [Android Developer documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume%28float,%20float%29).