# How to do logarithmic binning on a histogram?

Tags: c++, histogram, logarithm, binning

I'm looking for a technique to logarithmically bin some data sets. We've got data with values ranging from *_min* to *_max* (floats >= 0) and the user needs to be able to specify a varying number of bins *_num_bins* (some int n).

I've implemented a solution taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472747/convert-linear-scale-to-logarithmic) and some help on scaling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value) but my solution stops working when my data values lie below 1.0.

```
class Histogram {
double _min, _max;
int _num_bins;
......
};

double Histogram::logarithmicValueOfBin(double in) const {
    if (in == 0.0)
        return _min;

    double b = std::log(_max / _min) / (_max - _min);
    double a = _max / std::exp(b * _max);

    double in_unscaled = in * (_max - _min) / _num_bins + _min;
    return a * std::exp(b * in_unscaled) ;
}
```

When the data values are all greater than 1 I get nicely sized bins and can plot properly. When the values are less than 1 the bins come out more or less the same size and we get way too many of them.

Comment: Don't use [float/double] == [value]. Because computers cannot represent exact values. Use an epsilon instead: `if(std::abs(in - x) < 0.00001)` (or some other acceptable small value).

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bf7eaa25bcf1b9b ?

Comment: If you're willing to sacrifice significant accuracy, frexp and ldexp can make this _really_ fast. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f7477995f36930f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by reimplementing an [opensource version of Matlab's logspace function](https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-linspace/blob/master/index.js).

Given a range and a number of bins you need to create an evenly spaced numerical sequence

```
module.exports = function linspace(a,b,n) {
  var every = (b-a)/(n-1),
      ranged = integers(a,b,every);

  return ranged.length == n ? ranged : ranged.concat(b);
}
```

After that you need to loop through each value and with your base (e, 2 or 10 most likely) store the power and you get your bin ranges.

```
module.exports.logspace = function logspace(a,b,n) {
  return linspace(a,b,n).map(function(x) { return Math.pow(10,x); });
}
```

I rewrote this in C++ and it's able to support ranges > 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following

```
// Create isolethargic binning
    int     T_MIN   = 0;                    //The lower limit i.e. 1.e0
    int     T_MAX   = 8;                    //The uper limit   i.e. 1.e8
    int     ndec    = T_MAX - T_MIN;        //Number of decades
    int     N_BPDEC = 1000;                 //Number of bins per decade
    int     nbins   = (int) ndec*N_BPDEC;   //Total number of bins
    double  step    = (double) ndec / nbins;//The increment 
    double  tbins[nbins+1];                 //The array to store the bins

    for(int i=0; i <= nbins; ++i)
        tbins[i] = (float) pow(10., step * (double) i + T_MIN);
```