# Map a linear scale to a logarithmic one with both scales having variable min/max

Tags: math, scale, logarithm

Lets say that I have a linear scale [100-1000] and I want to map it to a [10-200] scale on a logarithmic basis.

```
100 becomes 10
1000 becomes 200
450 however becomes lower than 95 since the new scale is logarithmic.
```

I need a formula that if given the min/max of both scales, it takes any number within the linear scale and returns the logarithmic scale equivalent.

I tried to use the formula suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472747/convert-linear-scale-to-logarithmic) question but when using the numbers provided by the author as a test, I get 0.97 as a result instead of 1.02 which is apparently the correct one.

Comment: You've already asked this.

Answer (score 0):

Logarithmic scale is represented by equation

```
Y = a + b * log(X)
```

for some convenient logarithm base (decimal or natural)

Make equation for two border points (I use log10):

```
a + b * log10(100) = a + b * 2 = 10
a + b * log10(1000) = a + b * 3 = 200
b = 190
a = 10 - 380 = -370
```

so formula is

```
Y = -370 + 190 * log10(X)
for X=450 Y=134
```

Comment: I think you solved the reverse problem given that according to the author _"450 however becomes **lower** than 95 since the new scale is logarithmic."_. Your 134 is clearly more than 95.

Comment: @SergGr I believe that **logarithmic scale** maps 10-100-1000-10000 to equal-spaced values like 1,2,3,4, and here geometric mean value 316.2 maps to middle 105. Perhaps you are right, and author really wants **exponential scale**

Answer (score 0):

Meteor I believe that the formula in the referenced answer is correct but it's application to case `x=5` is wrong. `1.02` clearly can't be a valid mapping of `5` because `5` is slightly before the middle in the `[0.1; 10]` range (the middle is `5.05`) and `1.02` is slightly above the middle of the logarithmic range `[0.1; 10]` (the middle is `1.0`). This is probably due to the rounding errors by @DietrichEpp

Also I think that the formula he uses is a bit more prone to rounding errors. Particularly I think that starting from

```
y = a' * exp(b*(x-x1))
```

will produce a better formula. In such case `a'` is clearly `y1`.

`b` is still calculated the same way as

```
b = log (y2/y1) / (x2-x1)
```

The main difference is that in this formula `a' = a*exp(b*x1)` (where `a` is the `a` in @DietrichEpp's answer). If `x1` is anything big, this reduces a lot of rounding errors.

For your particular case using `e` (2.71828...) as the base for logarithm and exponent I get `b = 0,00332859141506` and `a' = 10`