# What do the bands in the AudioSpectrumListener represent?

Tags: javafx, media, spectrum

This question is related to this [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54925007/230513). Like [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54927406/230513), I'm having a look at the [`AudioSpectrumListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioSpectrumListener.html), but my question is "what do those 128 bands represent?" A band is usually define by a frequency in Hz. So, shall I just estimate that the frequencies measured are from 20 Hz to 20.000 Hz and I just divide the range of 19.980 Hz by 128?
Or does the central frequency of each band is following a logarithmic rule, so the visual representation is closer to what the human is hearing ?

I looked for informations in the Oracle documentation but I didn't really found an answer to that question.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See also [`audioSpectrumNumBands`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#audioSpectrumNumBandsProperty).

Comment: @trashgod : Thank you. But what a pity it follows a linear scale and not a logarithmic one. The human ears have a logarithmic approach to make the difference between two sounds.

Comment: See also [*Convert Linear scale to Logarithmic*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19472747/230513).