# How to play background sound through out application?

Tags: android, audio, android-asynctask, background-process

How can I play Background Sound throughout my application, even if activities keeps on changing.

I have found code for playing sound in background for one activity as:

```
public class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.test_cbr); 
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping 
        player.setVolume(100,100); 
        player.start(); 
        return null;
   }
}
```

I am not getting anyway to play sound in application content not activity context.

So I think there must be some way to achieve this using singleton class or service?

[Play Background Sound in android applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043059/play-background-sound-in-android-applications/21043243#21043243)

[How to play audio in android](http://javapapers.com/android/how-to-play-audio-in-android/)

I have followed above both links but it doesn't seems to help me though, its playing sound but not with my instruction from second time, first it works where ever I want to start.

Any Help would be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: I can implement this by creating a separate `Media Adapter class` this class will taken care of the sound(`Media Player`).

Comment: will that work through out application without interrupt while going to another activities?

Comment: Sound is playing as far as you can't Stop a Application

Comment: @SimplePlan can you give me example code of that?

Comment: @TMA try as per my answer.

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja : Use a `Service` - I appreciate you say you've already tried that but it didn't work but post your code you tried so people can help you fix it. Don't just post links.

Comment: Yes actually I am trying service thing only right now I have few more links on that if it doesn't help me I will update my question for sure. @Squonk