# Android sound cuts out when played on first screen

Tags: android, audio, mp3

I've used the code [from this existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32844746/playing-sounds-on-splash-screen-start-up/32845119#32845119?newreg=ba741211adee4f88bf1b93b30d117ff4) to play an MP3 file:

```
package com.mjr.testsound

import android.media.MediaPlayer
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                val mp: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.guitar3)
                mp.start()
            }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that it cuts out after a second if it's played in the MAIN startup activity, but it works fine if played in a second activity. Any idea what's happening?

Also I know that the activity is not terminating, I've logged the activity lifecycle and the cut out happens well before OnPause is logged.

Comment: Are you navigating from the first activity to another activity as soon as the first activity opens up  ?

Comment: Since this is a question where 2 activities need comparing it would be helpful to add the relevant code from each activity. Not just the mp3 init code.

Comment: I've updated the original post's code with literally all the only extra code I have inserted in the OnCreate method of the MainActivity of a completely new empty project. The problem still occurs

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems last week when implementing a media player. You have to be careful to start it correctly and release the resources.

In combination with a CompletionListener I got a working solution. Before that, I had non-reproducible failures.

I have packed the whole thing into the method `playSound()`. This method gets called in an onClick event, if one of my buttons is clicked.

Mediaplayer is first initialised in the activity with:

```
MediaPlayer soundTest = null;
```

related method:

```
    public void playSound() {

    try {

        if (soundTest != null){
            soundTest.reset();
            soundTest.release();
            soundTest = null;
        }
        soundTest = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.coins);

        soundTest.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                    soundTest = null;
                }
            }
        });
        soundTest.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Maybe this helps you.