# How to play the audio file in android using mediaplayer when screen sleeps

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play the audio files using media player. It will stop after screen lock. It is annoying can anyone suggest, how to handle this??
I want to play the music even screen goes off.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: U can have a service thats play audio using media player.

Comment: @kevz Can u please post some example code ?

Comment: take a look at this http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-ii

Comment: did you acquire the wake lock permission

Comment: You need to use service to play your music though screen lock

Comment: @Archana Check these http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/03/how-to-create-services-in-android.html , http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778

Comment: you should do it in your manifest or in your activity to make it available after   screen lock

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043059/play-background-sound-in-android-applications

Comment: I have already created a class which extends activity class how to implement this service class now.?? There is a lot of change to do if i go for service class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use  [**Media Playback**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.action.PLAY";
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
        mMediaPlayer = ... // initialize it here
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
    }
}

/** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    player.start();
}
```

}

Comment: additionally(if required) you can return START_STICKY in onStartCommand. START_STICKY tells the OS to recreate the service after it has enough memory and call onStartCommand() again with a null intent.