# How to play sound in whole Android Application background

Tags: android, audio, service, background

Hello stackoverflow's members !!

I have terrible problem, I don't know how to implement service to play sound in background in my whole application.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App) but it seems to be not working for me.

Have you guys any idea how to do that?

Comment: Check this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm

Comment: It's not what I mean. I want to this:
My app starts, and sound starts, I'm switching between Activities and sound not stop . Sound stop when I click the button.

Comment: Use a service like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043059/play-background-sound-in-android-applications?answertab=active#tab-top