# Play audio background even the application exit

Tags: android

I'am currently working a mobile application for radio streaming. The problem is when I exit the application the audio stops playing. any idea about this? I really need a help. thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play Background Sound in android applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043059/play-background-sound-in-android-applications)

Answer (score 0):

You can use service to do that.
[Follow the link](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just play the song using **foreground service** showing music player notification in the notification panel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Service and run it on the foreground. Here is the [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/) to a comprehensive implementation.