# Pan Stereo Audio Android

Tags: android, audio

Is there a best way to go about panning stereo audio in an android app? I have been looking for some decent audio libraries but have yet to come up with anything solid.

Comment: Are you dealing with the audio at a sample level? If so, it's pretty trivial to do the panning yourself.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to implementing audio into anything really. There is to be an audio file within the app that on start will play. The user can then pan that track left or right. There will also be other audio files that can play at the same time that will should not pan. That being said, I suppose I'm looking for a method for MediaPlayer or something else that will pan only that track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MediaPlayer.setVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume%28float,%20float%29) allows you to set the volume of the left and right channels independently.

For more details have a look at [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215459/android-mediaplayer-setvolume-function).

Comment: Ah perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!