# How can i change the volume of an mp3 in android?

Tags: java, android, mp3

There are tools to increase the volume of mp3's. Is this possible to do in java on android devices?

I could not find much information about this on the web.

If it is not possible to write it in java directly, would it be possible to create a C program on the system level that does the mp3 processing and can be called from an android application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215459/android-mediaplayer-setvolume-function

Comment: I am sorry. The question in the link you gave is about changing the device volume. I want to to change the mp3 file.

Comment: you mean the bitrate?

Comment: No, the volume.  Of the sound encoded in the file.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: correct

Comment: This is simply data processing - it is possible in *either* Java or in a C library invoked through jni.

Comment: But is there a library for java (which i can use with android/dalvik) which makes that easy?

Comment: You can't change mp3 volume without: 1) decoding the data to PCM 2) multiplying each sample by some value <1 3) re-encoding the samples back to mp3. I hope your question was really about something different than this! And there is a library that would help you - ffmpeg, any compilation for Android will do this.