# How to Increase and decrease mediaplayer sound when sliding finger up and down?

Tags: android

I am new to android development and currently I'm developing simple music player app. Here question is that how to increase and decrease music player volume when sliding finger up on my main music player activity.

this is my music player fragment

```
public class Player extends Fragment implements WheelModel.Listener,MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnForward;
private ImageButton btnBackward;
private ImageButton btnNext;
private ImageButton btnPrevious;
private ImageButton btnRepeat;
private ImageButton btnShuffle;
private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private TextView songTitleLabel;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
// Media Player
public static MediaPlayer mp,mp2;
VisualizerView mVisualizerView;
SliderView sl;
private Visualizer mVisualizer;
// Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
private SongsManager songManager;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int currentSongIndex = 0;
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private ArrayList<SongModel> songsList = new ArrayList<SongModel>();
int songIndex;
AudioManager audioManager;
SongAdapter songAdapter;

public Player(int position) {
    songIndex = position;
}

public Player() {

}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player, container, false);
        ClickWheel wheel = (ClickWheel) android.findViewById(R.id.wheel);
        wheel.getModel().addListener(this);
        return android;

    }
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

    btnPlay = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnPrevious = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnRepeat = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    btnShuffle = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
    songProgressBar = (SeekBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitleLabel = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songTitleLabel.setSelected(true);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);


    mp = new MediaPlayer();

    songManager = new SongsManager();
    utils = new Utilities();

    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

    if (songIndex == 0) {
        playSong(0);
    } else {
        playSong(songIndex);
    }
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.pause();
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            } else {
                // Resume song
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.start();
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }
            }

        }
    });
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
            }else{
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }
        }
    });
    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
            }else{
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }

        }
    });
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }

        }
    });
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
            }else{
                playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
            }

        }
    });
    btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isRepeat){
                isRepeat = false;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }else{
                isRepeat = true;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isShuffle = false;
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }
        }
    });
    btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isShuffle){
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }else{
                isShuffle= true;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isRepeat = false;
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }
        }
    });

}
public void playSong(int songIndex) {
    try {
        Log.e("playSong()...", "....is called");
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).getSongPath());
        mp.prepare();
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).getSongTitle();
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
        mp.start();
        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.i("song...songIndex...", "..." + songIndex);
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    if(resultCode == 100){
        currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
        // play selected song
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

        songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));

        songCurrentDurationLabel.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        int progress =(int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));

        songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
private void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(isRepeat){
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else if(isShuffle){
        Random rand = new Random();
        currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else{
        if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        }else{
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

}
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
    updateProgressBar();
}
@Override
public void onDialPositionChanged(WheelModel sender, int nicksChanged) {
    getActivity().setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp2 =MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),R.raw.djlazer);
    mp2.start();
}}
```

If anyone know the logic of these please help me for this.

thanks in advance...

Comment: It must be fullfil your requirement
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215459/android-mediaplayer-setvolume-function>.

Comment: This is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

The event when user releases his finger is MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. I'm not aware if there are any guidelines which prohibit using View.OnTouchListener instead of onClick(), most probably it depends of situation.
Here's my sample working code:

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i am putting this inside ACTION_UP audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8, 0);  It is working for increasing volume and when putting this on ACTION_DOWN it is not working for decreasing sound

Comment: if it is working for you ACTION_UP then please accept this as an answer , for ACTION_DOWN you may need to check code. Thanks.


For more reference visit link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html