# How do you make a mediaplayer play a sound louder?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my application a sound is triggered by a button click, but the sound is relatively quiet and requires me to manually increase the volume on my phone to hear. Is there a way to increase the volume so that it get's louder quicker? Our plays louder by default?

Edit: the set volume function didn't have an effect on the overall loudness without physically changing the volume on my phone. Am I doing something wrong or have the wrong values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: MediaPlayer setVolume function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215459/android-mediaplayer-setvolume-function)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `setVolume` method

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.09f , 0.09f);//0,09f = 90% of volume
```

> public void setVolume (float leftVolume, 
>                   float rightVolume)